# Python: Create 5-6 groups from a dataset so that the groups are balanced across 3 different variables (decile, population size & region)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, subset, sklearn-pandas

I was given already filtered datasets. The request is to create 5-6 equally sized groups that are balanced/stratified across 3 different variables. I have two datasets to do this for, one with about 540 rows and the other with about 880 rows. The relevant columns are:

- **AreaID** - unique ID for geographic region
- **Region** - one of region names *(A, B, C, D)* one in particular is underrepresented
- **Decile** - an already calculated decile ranking based on another variable *(range 1-10)*
- **Population** - population of said geographic region *(ranges from 0 to over a million)*
- **PopGroup** - I created four labels for population *(0-50K, 50k-100k, 100k-1M, 1M+)*

This isn't for machine learning. I need 5-6 groups so that deciles, regions and population are equally distributed across groups. I added the PopGroup based on previous threads stating that continuous variables should be binned. Based on my bin cutoffs, the 4 groups are obviously imbalanced. I then created a stratifying variable on the concatenation of the popgroup and region. Adding deciles to the stratifying variable would only create even more groups to stratify on an already small dataset and I hoped the mostly uniform distribution of deciles would randomly be split evenly. As it is, I had to drop one whole region (n=6) and one region_popgroup label from each respective dataset because of errors about only having one sample in a split group.

```
df['region_popgroup'] = df['Region'] + "_" + df['PopGroup'].astype(str)
```

After looking at the various splitting methods: StratifiedShuffleSplit, StratifiedKFold, GroupShuffleSplit, GroupKFold, ShuffleSplit, MultilabelStratifiedKFold, I went with the following:

```
train1, test1 = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=df[['region_popgroup']])
train2, test2 = train_test_split(train1, test_size=0.25, random_state=42, stratify=train1[['region_popgroup']])
train3, test3 = train_test_split(train2, test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify=train2[['region_popgroup']])
test4, test5 = train_test_split(train3, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, stratify=train3[['region_popgroup']])

testgroups = pd.concat([test1, test2, test3, test4, test5], axis=0)
```

I iteratively changed the test_size, taking the leftover train set from one split to be the source for the next split, so that I'd have 5 similarly sized groups. The deciles didn't always get equal distribution but were very even except for a couple of decile labels. I think the regions and pop groups ended up good enough.

Is there a better solution? Currently I had to drop the drastically underrepresented groups that need to be manually assigned later. I'd prefer a solution that eliminated the manual group picking. Also, I would have to add a first row with test_size=0.167, if the request really preferred 6 groups. So, is there a method that allows me to choose and compare the results for a number of groups/folds (ie n_splits=5). Also, is there a better way to handle the population size? Is there a method that allows stratification on a continuous variable or should I bin the populations differently? I thought this would've been more straightforward. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a solution for this but I wonder how you dealt with the rare classes. e.g. if you wish to have 5 groups but a very rare class is only present once. Stata has modules for clinical trials that do this out of the box but I found no good solution for python.